# How do I synchronize the threads without using pthread_join()?

Tags: c++, synchronization, pthreads, mutex

I have created a simple c++ program which is used for logging. I am creating threads in a for loop which runs 1000 times in `test.cpp` which is the driver file. `pthread_create` calls the print function in `tt.cpp` which writes the input parameter i.e i, in `file.txt`. 
I wish to synchronize the threads.

I have tried using `pthread_join` which synchronized the threads but I wish to synchronize the threads without using join.

I know that if a thread is locked, a lot of threads will be waiting until it gets unlocked and after that thread is unlocked, any one of the waiting threads will lock the function. So, I tried to use a static integer variable in `tt.cpp` and tried to compare it with the input parameter so that I can use `pthread_cond_wait` and `pthread_wait_signal` but I got segmentation fault on comparing.

```
 /* if(j == *((int *)input)))
    This comparison gave me a segmentation fault */


-------------------------test.cpp---------------------------------
#include "thr.h"


pthread_mutex_t loc;
FILE *thePrintFile = NULL;

int main()
{
    pthread_mutex_init(&loc,NULL);

    pthread_t p;
    thePrintFile = fopen("file.txt","r+");
    for(int i =0; i<1000;i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&p,NULL,print,(void *)i);
    }
    for(int k = 0; k<100000;k++);
    /* i have used it to ensure that the main thread 
       doesn't exit before the pthreads finish writing */
    return 0;

}

    ------------------------tt.cpp------------------------------------
    #include "thr.h"

    extern pthread_mutex_t loc;
    extern FILE *thePrintFile;

    void* print(void *input)
    {
        if(pthread_mutex_trylock(&loc) == 0)
        {   

            fprintf(thePrintFile,"%s%d\n",(int *)input);
            fflush(thePrintFile);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&loc);
        }   
    }

    -----------------------------thr.h--------------------------------
    #ifndef THR_H_INCLUDED
    #define THR_H_INCLUDED

    void* print(void *input);

    #endif
```

Given below is a part of file.txt .

```
1
5
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
18
19
20
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
21
201
202
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: sorry if my question is not clear. I want the threads to work in order, like first it should write 0 then 1,2,3..... and so on.

Comment: You show that you get a segmentation fault on a certain line. That line is not in the actual code you posted. Then you have a void * return type for your print section but you don't return anything.

Comment: is that C or C++ ? you tagged it C++, but code is more C

Comment: And, you cast an int to a void *?

Comment: Creating 1000 threads might not be a good idea.

Comment: @OznOg it's a cpp code .

Comment: @fonZ I thought to send it as a parameter,I need to cast it

Comment: @AkshitAchara you can't just cast int to a pointer, that is asking for problems. It might work, but it might not also = undefined behavior.

Comment: @fonZ I am getting an error if I don't cast it to void *                                    
  error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘void*’ [-fpermissive]
   pthread_create(&p,NULL,print,i);

Comment: @AkshitAchara your function argument is void *input, the type is void *. Change it to int input, it wont give an error without cast.

Comment: @fonZ I just wrote that line to show the approach that I tried but I was not able to synchronize using that approach.

Comment: @fonZ the function must take a single void* argument.I can't take ints. 
    https://w3.cs.jmu.edu/kirkpams/OpenCSF/Books/cs361/html/POSIXArgs.html

Comment: @then use something else than Posix, there are way better frameworks for threads. This stuff if from the last century.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To synchronize the threads properly, you need to use a synchronization device such as a [condition variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable). Since you are using C++, you are much better off using its [built-in threads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) rather than the raw pthread API.

For example, this code synchronizes 1000 threads so that each prints its own ID using a condition variable and mutex pair to ensure that the IDs are printed in order, as tracked by a separate variable shared by all. It is not very efficient because all threads fight for the same mutex, but it works correctly. It could be made more efficient by creating a condition variable for each thread, but doing it correctly would require a better understanding of your actual use case.

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

static std::mutex mutex;
static std::condition_variable condvar;
static int whos_next;

static void work(int id) {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{mutex};
  // wait for our turn
  condvar.wait(lock, [=]() { return whos_next == id; });
  // it's our turn now - print our thread ID
  std::cout << id << '\n';
  ++whos_next;
  condvar.notify_all();    // notify the next thread to run
}

int main() {
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    threads.push_back(std::thread([=]() { work(i); }));

  for (auto &t: threads)
    t.join();
}
```

Note that the above code's use of `join` is not to synchronize the threads with each other (they synchronize among themselves using the mutex/condition), but for its intended purpose: to wait for the threads to finish before exiting `main()`. C++ even requires that you do that before destructing the `std::thread` object, so removing the join results in program termination. You can easily prove that the threads don't rely on `join` for synchronization, e.g. by inserting a sleep before joins, or by joining them in reverse order.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Is there any way this can be done with pthreads or can this code be synchronized without using t.join()?

Comment: @AkshitAchara In the comments to the question you explicitly said your code was C++, so I gave you a C++ answer. However it should be straightforward to port it to pthreads which also support synchronization using [condition variables and mutexes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/6je9h032r/index.html).

Comment: Your answer serves the purpose but you are using join.If I remove the join statement.                        
output:                                                                                                                                 0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted (core dumped) . Is this because the main terminates before the threads stop execution?

Comment: @AkshitAchara Yes, this is why you get core dumped. You can replace the `t.join()` in this answer by waiting on another lock, and when `work()` is done, notify that lock to end the program.

Comment: @AkshitAchara Here `join` is used for its intended purpose: to wait for the threads to finish. (C++ even requires that you do that before destructing the `std::thread` object, this is why you get a crash when you just remove the join.) You can insert a sleep before joins to convince yourself that I'm not "cheating", i.e. that the threads synchronize correctly even if they are "joined" only after they've already exited.

Comment: Another way to prove that this code doesn't depend on join for synchronization is to join them in reverse order (or, indeed, in any order whatsoever) and observe that they still synchronize correctly. I've now amended the answer to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

I see multiple problems in your code.

- You show that you get a segmentation fault on a certain line. That line is not in the actual code you posted.
- You have a void * return type for your print section but you don't return anything.
- You cast int to void *. The size of a pointer might not be the same as the size of int. Change your print function argument to be int instead. Then the cast is unnecessary.
- You can't write with 1000 threads to the same file at the same time. So in this case there is no reason to create threads, because you have to execute them sequentially anyways. But if you do, then you have to join them.

Then let's look at the comparison you try to make:

```
if(j == *((int *)input)))
```

j is obviously int. input is void *. At the basis input was int. Because casting int to void * is not guaranteed to be safe, casting it back is not safe either. Imagine that int is 64bits and a pointer is 32bit. If you cast your int to void * you lose 32 bits. Then you cast from 32bit to 64bit, so you add 32bit of 0's. Obviously that is going to give problems.

Consider using C++11, that will greatly improve your code.
https://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/12/16/cpp-11-thread-tutorial/